# Change android name from "android-..."

Tags: networking, dhcp, device-name

I have many android devices connected to my network but they are all showing as android-[string of hexacecimal].

My OnePlus 3t (v7.1.1) is one of the devices. I have changed the name of the device but it still shows up as android-xxxxxxxxxx....

Is there a way of fixing this.

Comment: How did you change the device's name?

Comment: "showing" where? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

What you wish to change is the device's `hostname`. On certain ROMs such as LineageOS, you may do so via the `Device hostname` setting, located inside the `Developer options`. You can access them by typically tapping the `Build number` information, placed inside the `About phone` setting, seven or more times.

If the `Device hostname` setting is missing, you may achieve the same result by either using a computer and sending commands via `adb`, or by installing a terminal emulator app.

While I won't cover the topic of setting adb and USB debugging on, the command to use with adb is

```
adb shell "setprop net.hostname <hostname>"
```

If using a terminal emulator, instead, the command to use is

```
setprop net.hostname <hostname>
```

In both cases, replace `<hostname>` with a name of your choice, and press the Enter key to run the command.

Comment: The `setprop` command is only available to root so it is necessary to have the `su` binary available. Also, setting hostname using this approach will only remain in effect until reboot.